# Error after deploying asp.net core angular in IIS Cannot find module 'aspnet-webpack' at Function.Module._resolveFilename

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0

I create an ASP.net Core with Angular project. When I run it from my visual studio I get no error but when I publish and deploy to an machine with IIS I get the below error. I have installed ".NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle" and nodeJS. is there anything else that I am missing?

> NodeInvocationException: Webpack dev middleware failed because of an
>   error while loading 'aspnet-webpack'. Error was: Error: Cannot find
>   module 'aspnet-webpack' at Function.Module._resolveFilename
>   (module.js:538:15) at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25) at
>   Module.require (module.js:587:17) at require
>   (internal/module.js:11:18) at Object.
>   (C:\Windows\TEMP\hnfsrsh3.ahy:83:19) at **webpack_require**
>   (C:\Windows\TEMP\hnfsrsh3.ahy:20:30) at createWebpackDevServer
>   (C:\Windows\TEMP\hnfsrsh3.ahy:62:26) at
>   C:\Windows\TEMP\cbaevvou.1oi:114:19 at IncomingMessage.
>   (C:\Windows\TEMP\cbaevvou.1oi:133:38) at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
>   Current directory is: C:\website

thanks